# Keep the text in ckeditor text editor after getting error of form_validation in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation, ckeditor

I want to keep the text which has been styled for sometime in `Ckeditor` even if there is an error in `form_validation` and the browser redirects to the previous page that you have been working on.

Of course, I've used `set_value()` in my input options, but the problem still remains.

this is the code in my view file:

```
<? $news_Body = array('name' => 'news_Body', 'value' => set_value('news_Body'), 'tabindex' => '16'); echo form_textarea($news_Body)?>
<?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor); ?>
```

All of the other inputs which `set_value()` has been used in them keep their value except the `text_area` with `Ckeditor!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added [a validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) for `news_Body` ? If not, `set_value` will not work.;

Comment: Oops!!! as I checked my validation rules, I noticed that the only missing part is the rule for news_Body! Thanks dude :)